# Display merged pdf in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to display a merged pdf file in an IFrame. If I hard code the ng-source everything works OK.

```
<iframe ng-src="~/Content/PdfFiles/MergedPdfs/Test.pdf" style="width:100%; height:600px;" type='application/pdf'></iframe>
```

if I try like ... The value of response is "~/Content/PdfFiles/MergedPdfs/Test.pdf"

```
getMergedPdf().then(function (response) 
{
     $scope.mergedPdfFile = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(response);
});

<iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(mergedPdfFile)}}" style="width:100%; height:600px;" type='application/pdf'></iframe>
```

The value of the ng-srs is empty.

If I try  ... I am getting 404 error

```
getMergedPdf().then(function (response) {
     $scope.mergedPdfFile = response;
 });
```

And this is the http request

```
 function getMergedPdf()
 {
     return $http.post(baseUrl + 'Admin/getMergedPdf').then(function (response) {
         return response.data;
     })
 }
```

Comment: have you tried `response.data`?

Comment: Thank you . I added my http request function. I am doing response.data there.

Comment: what is the FULL 404 error?  what URL is it *trying* to go to?  that should give you some clue about what is being passed incorrectly through the promise chain...

Comment: Seems like a wrong URL. Try checking what is the actual value of `src` on the generated HTML for each of those two situations.